# keep elements of an np.ndarray by values of another np.array (vectorized)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an np array, for example

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
```

and another vector, which represents the columns I want to keep for each row:

```
y = [1,2,0].
```

Is there a vectorized way to keep only the relevant X[i,j]s? The desired output would be

```
X_new = np.array([[2],
                  [6],
                  [7]])
```

I came up with few ways to get the desired output. One way would by iterate over rows of X[i,:] and then `hstack`ing over all the rows. A vectorized but highly unreproducible way is to reshape X into an `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`, transform y to `y_new = (i*(ncol+1)) + y) -> y_new=[0+1, 1*3+2, 2*3+0]=[1,5,6]`, then keep only the X[y_new] and then reshape again.

Is there a simple way to get X_new without all the pyrotechnics?

Comment: `X[np.arange(3),y]`

Comment: You could also do: np.choose(y, X.T)